# Figuring out if $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x^6y^1(x^2+1)}{(x^6+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find out if the limit exists.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x^6y^1(x^2+1)}{(x^6+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

First, I approached the limit from $y=0$, and the result was $\frac{0}{x^7}$. Then, I approached from $x = 0$, and the result was $\frac{0}{y^3}$. This made me assume that the limit does not exist. However, Wolfram Alpha calculated the limit as zero. What is the solution to this question?

Comment: Looks like you found the same limit along both paths, so why assume the limit doesn't exist? (Not to suggest you should assume that it does!)

Answer (score 3):

Since this term has some $(x^2+y^2)$ term, it may be inspiring to use polar coordinate to investigate its behaviour first. Thus, under polar coordinate, we have the limit becomes
$$\lim_{r\to0}\dfrac{r^7\cos^6\theta\sin\theta(1+r^2\cos^2\theta)}{r^2(r^4\cos^4\theta+1)r}=\lim_{r\to0}r^4\times\left(\dfrac{\cos^6\theta\sin\theta(1+r^2\cos^2\theta)}{(r^4\cos^4\theta+1)}\right)$$
As you can see the RHS term is bounded as the denominator is at least 1, so sandwich theorem!

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $x=0 \land y\neq 0$ and for $y=0 \land x\neq 0$ the expression is equal to zero otherwise by AM-GM

$$\left|\frac{-x^6y^1(x^2+1)}{(x^6+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le \frac{2x^6|y|}{2|x^3||y|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{|x^3|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le x^2 \to 0$$